# awk - wrong comparing floating point numbers

Tags: if-statement, awk, floating-point

```
echo '"MSE_DB": -20.100000000000001,' | awk '/MSE_DB/ {mse_db = substr($2, 1, length($2)-1)} END {printf("MSE_DB %f ", mse_db); if (mse_db > -22.0)
{print ">-22.0"}; if (mse_db<= -22.0) {print "<= -22.0"} }'

MSE_DB -20.100000 <= -22.0
```

What am I missing?

expected to see -20.1 > -22

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`substr()` is a string function so the value it returns and stores in `mse_db` is a string and so you're doing a string comparison (i.e. alphabetic character-by-character), not a numeric comparison.

Add a `0` to the `substr()` result to make `mse_db` a number instead of a string:

```
echo '"MSE_DB": -20.100000000000001,' | awk '/MSE_DB/ {mse_db = substr($2, 1, length($2)-1)+0} END {printf("MSE_DB %f ", mse_db); if (mse_db > -22.0)
{print ">-22.0"}; if (mse_db<= -22.0) {print "<= -22.0"} }'
MSE_DB -20.100000 >-22.0
```

but you can just get rid of the `substr()` and add `0` since awk already knows how to strip trailing chars during a numeric conversion:

```
echo '"MSE_DB": -20.100000000000001,' | awk '/MSE_DB/ {mse_db = $2+0} END {printf("MSE_DB %f ", mse_db); if (mse_db > -22.0)
{print ">-22.0"}; if (mse_db<= -22.0) {print "<= -22.0"} }'
MSE_DB -20.100000 >-22.0
```

Comment: Thanks @ed ! actually suspected this is the case, but after seeing that
`printf("2xMSE_DB %f ", 2*mse_db)`
yields correct result, convinced my self that `mse_db` is already floating point number..

Comment: You're welcome. Doing `2*mse_db` would convert the string contained in `mse_db` into a floating point number **for that statement**, as would just printing it using `%f`, but that doesn't change the "type" of `msd_db`, it's still whatever type it was before that statement.

Answer (score 1):

You can refactor/reduce your `awk` to this:

```bash
awk '/MSE_DB/ {
   mse_db = $2+0
}
END {
   print "MSE_DB", mse_db, (mse_db > -22.0 ? "> -22.0" : "<= -22.0")
}' <<< '"MSE_DB": -20.100000000000001,'
```

This will give output:

```bash
MSE_DB -20.1 > -22.0
```

Answer (score 0):

there's nothing wrong with using `substr()` as long as you prepend an unary `"+"` to the numeric-string to force numeric comparisons (even if the value were negative) :

```
echo 'MSE_DB: -20.100000000000001,' |
```

> ```
> {m,g,n}awk '
>  /MSE_DB/ { mse_db = substr(__=$(++_+_), _, length(__)-_--) 
>  } END    { 
>             printf("MSE_DB [ %s ] :: %*s %*.*f\n", mse_db, _+=++_,   
>                   (__=_-_*(_+_+_)*_) < +mse_db ? ">" : "<=",--_,__) }'
> ```

```
MSE_DB [ -20.100000000000001 ] ::  > -22.0
```

Comment: Thanks @RARE, this looks impressive/advanced, but I can't figure out how this code works - can't understand how those underscore , + , -  etc interact with "regular" / trivial use of awk..

Comment: @flyck : they're just basic pre-increment (`++x`), pre-decrement (`--x`), post-increment (`x++`), post-decrement (`x--`), add/subtract-assign (`+=  -=`) etc. say `_+=++_` :: `_` was zero before, so add-assign a `0` pre-incremented to `1`, which yields `2`. ::::::::::::::::::::: :::::::::::::::::: :::::::::::::  Then `_-_*(_+_+_)*_` is simply `2 - 2 * (2 + 2 + 2) * 2` , :::::::::::::  :::::::::::::  :::::::::::::  :::::::::::::  which you can simplify to `2 - 4 * 6` —> `2 - 24`  giving you that `-22`